# how to exclude current node from a view inside a node commerce kickstart

Tags: views, commerce

I know variations of this have been asked left and right but I can't get this to work.

I have a Commerce Kickstart Product Display (shopping cart form, basically a node).

Inside this content type is a display field which uses ViewField to insert a View inside the form. This View is a list of related products (nodes in the same category). I pass the category of the current node as a token %1 to the View and it works great.

However, I'd like to further exclude the current node (ie. the product being displayed) from this Related Products view.

I tried adding a second Contextual Filter:

Indexed Content: Node ID
Provide Default Argument: Content ID From URL

and then checking the 'Exclude' box in the More section.

And this does nothing. The current node still displays in the Related Products View.

NOTES:
1. FWIW: This View is of Type: 'Product Display' (from Commerce) as opposed to 'Content' or 'Message')

2. There is no default argument for 'Node ID'. Only 'Indexed Content: Node ID'. Probably because of the type of View (I cloned an existing view in Commerce Kickstart as a template.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rather just pass the product display node id as a second parameter in your view field (you are allowed to use a comma separated list of arguments), and then don't bother with providing a default argument at all. The second argument to pass is [node:nid]

Comment: Then what do I use for the Contextual Filter?

Comment: Oh and how do I get it to be NOT NID=='current node'. (sigh) I wish these filters could just use SQL Queries.

Comment: You still add a second contextual filter, you just don't give it a default value because you are always passing it in. And in the contextual filter configuration settings right at the bottom is a dropwdown 'more' that will reveal the 'exclude' setting.